# rails - update_attributes for just part of the model; file uploading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to add the ability of a user to have several pictures associated with his / her user account.

I have the following classes:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assets
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :assets
end

class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :assetable, :polymorphic => true
  belongs_to :user
end
```

I want to have a screen that just has the upload image functionality:

```
def add_profile_picture 
  @user=User.find(params[:id])
  1.times {@user.assets.build}
end
```

form:

```
<%= form_for @user do |u| %>
  <%= u.fields_for :assets do |asset| %>
    <%= asset.file_field :asset %>
    <%= asset.text_field :description %><br />
  <% end %>
  <%=u.submit %>
<% end %>
```

When I submit, it looks like the id value goes in ok in development.log:

```
"id"=>"1"
```

but I get the error:

undefined method `update_attributes' for nil:NilClass

Since I just have the asset fields, is there anything special I need to do? Also, because the belongs_to :user exists, could that be causing problems?
Basically:

```
asset:
  user_id: 
  assetable_type:
  assetable_id:
```

Any help would be appreciated. Don't do much Rails forms stuff.

thx

edit #1

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def add_profile_picture 
    @user=User.find(params[:id])
    1.times {@user.assets.build}
  end
```

thx

Comment: Can you paste in the code for the related action in your controller?

Answer (score 0):

Okay - there are a few problems with your code here. I would highly recommend you read both the [Action Controller Overview](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html) and the [Rails Routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) guides to get some more information about this.

In any case, you're getting the error because the form you have there will be trying to use the `users#update` action in the `UsersController`.

You've got a couple options. One is to create the necessary routes for the custom action, or you can create a nested resource, and make a form for adding the asset.

In this case, you'd do something like this:

in `routes.rb`

```
resources :users do
  resources :assets, :only => [:new, :create] # Or any other actions you might want. It's best practise to limit these.
end
```

Then, in the `AssetsController`, you can do something similar to this:

```
def new
  @asset = Asset.new
end

def create
  @asset = Asset.new(params[:asset])
  @asset.user_id = params[:user_id] if params[:user_id]
  @asset.save!
end
```

and your form will look something like this:

```
<%= form_for @asset do |f| %>
  <%= f.file_field :asset %>
  <%= f.text_field :description %><br />
  <%=f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: thx for answering. so would the url be `/users/1/assets/edit` for the nested resource? Also, would this handle the belongs_to and the polymorphic relationship? thx again

Comment: looking into this - I'm aware that it's using the user#update; that is what is intended using nested attributes. Since the id is being passed in the post'd parameters, it seems like it should be working.